# ui centered horizontally to anchor point at the left not the center

Tags: html, css

What I want to do:
Social buttons at the bottom centered horizontally to the page. 
What I tried:

```css
.centered {
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  bottom: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="fa"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="fa"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="fa"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The problem that comes up:
It looks like that the anchor point is at the left of the whole ul and not in the middle. So it doesn't look equally centered on the page. If you look closely you can see that the  starts right at the center of the page.

I hope its clear what I want to achieve.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: why there is class ul in your css? There is no such in html

Comment: imho simplest solution would be `.centered{display: flex;
    justify-content: center;}`

Comment: Well, yes. it should not be a class. I try your solution out. Thanks

Comment: Easy as that. Solved the problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can use flex if you not aiming for older browsers https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

```css
.centered {
  display: flex; justify-content: center
}
```

```html
<div class="centered">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="fa"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="fa"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="fa"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

change left of ul to 50%

```css
ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

ul>li {
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="1">
  </li>
  <li class="2">
  </li>
  <li class="3">
  </li>
  <li class="4">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, but nah I want to use <ul> <li>and not divs. I  tired the solution above and it worked.

Comment: @Jona it works with ul tho...
Just change selectors `nav` to `ul` & `div` to `li`